# What is the Equivalent of N'something in Persian' in C# And LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, persian

Im trying to insert something in persian into my Database (SQL server 2008) from C# code.
The problem is when u insert in sql server you just simply use N'چیزی' for utf-8.But how 
Can u do that in LINQ ? (I dont wanna use stored procedures).
Thnks

Comment: Is this a question about translating or character encoding?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Stored Procedures?

Comment: It's utf-16, *not* utf-8,  SQL Server 2008 does not support utf-8.

Comment: And AFAIK, *all* VS source code is utf-16 also and saved as such.

Comment: I dont want to use stored procedure because my whole project is written with EF Inserts and updates . Its gonna take a lot of time to change everything into stored procedures right now! Actually my problem is that when im inserting "چیزی" into my table everything is ok except the last letter is inserted in Arabic like this "چیزي". Im using entity framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the string `"چیزی"` and make sure your `.cs` files are `UTF-8` too.

Use this as the parameter in a parameterized query or in whatever ORM you are using. The data access layer will take care of encoding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that VS saves source code files as utf-16, which should be more than sufficient.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - You could be right. One way or another, it is a Unicode encoding.

Comment: Actually my problem is that when im inserting "چیزی" into my table everything is ok except the last letter is inserted in Arabic like this "چیزي". Im using entity framework.

Comment: @user1240464 - You need to check your database collations and debug through your code to see whether the data inserted is what you expect.

Comment: There is no Ye(ي/ى)-Ke(ك/ک) insensitive collation available yet. These are 2 similar Arabic and Persian words which have the same meaning depending on the context but have different characters/codes.

Comment: @VahidN - That was exacly my problem.I wanted to compare two exact words but because of different codes in arabic and Persian the result of comparison was always false.I managed to fix this problem by using triggers on my table. thnks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

- LINQ to EF or LINQ to SQL will generate/use that N'' automatically everywhere:

```
    exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Users]
        set [Name] = @0
        where (([Id] = @1) and ([Name] = @2))
        ',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'User name 1',@1=1,@2=N'Vahid'
```

- Those N'ي' (Arabic Ye) or N'ى' (Persian Ye) both are the valid UTF-8 characters. So you need to convert between them yourself (before inserting the data) and it's not the duty of EF or SQL Server.
  [Some examples](http://www.dotnettips.info/Search?term=%D9%8A%20%D9%88%20%D9%83) about it (in Persian).